# Problems setting up data in UI-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I´m struggling with UI-grid trying to set it up properly.

I have a datastructure similar to this:

```
var arr = [
        {'name': 'a', age: '1'},
        {'name': 'b', age: '2'},
        {'name': 'c', age: '3'},
        {'name': 'd', age: '4'},
        {'name': 'e', age: '5'}
        ];
```

Im trying to present the data using `name` as columnHeader and `age`
as its data. So I would like the result to consist of only two rows.

Here is the code I am using:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
        enableSorting: true,
        columnDefs: [],
        data : []
      };

      var arr = [
        {'name': 'a', age: '1'},
        {'name': 'b', age: '2'},
        {'name': 'c', age: '3'},
        {'name': 'd', age: '4'},
        {'name': 'e', age: '5'}
        ];

          for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                var name = arr[i].name.toString();

                $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs.push({ name:name, field: 'age' });

              }


}]);
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gokiqQaT68xBuKnbwv7H?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
  var d = [];          
  var model = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var name = arr[i].name.toString();
      $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs.push({ name:name, field: 'age' });
      var a = $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[i].name.toString();
      model[a]=arr[i].age; 
  } 
   d.push(model); 
  $scope.gridOptions = { data: d };
```

Comment: Thank you. This give me a result of 2 columns. Name and Age. I would like it to be 5 columns where the headers are:
a | b | c | d | e....and on the second row...  1 | 2 | etc..

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!